# Ошибка "Request failed with status code 403" при загрузке фото в админ-панели

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-hook, crud

Я загружаю фото в админ-панели. И делаю fetch api, чтобы выгрузить на сайте карусель фото. Но получаю ошибку:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name:
'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request:
XMLHttpRequest, …} code : "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
```

Код:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { MdArrowBackIos, MdArrowForwardIos } from "react-icons/md";



export default function Main() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [secondData, setSecondData] = useState([]);

  const token = "mrfcaiL5UrlAu_zsWeADkwKKXFLxJK41";



  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSecondData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://130.61.61.186:8055/items/Slider",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        setSecondData(response.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchSecondData();
  }, []);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === secondData.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1
    );
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) =>
      prevIndex === 0 ? secondData.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1
    );
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <article className={styles.sections}>
       
        <section className={styles.slider}>
          {secondData.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <MdArrowBackIos
                className={styles.leftArrow}
                onClick={handlePrev}
              />
              <MdArrowForwardIos
                className={styles.rightArrow}
                onClick={handleNext}
              />

              <img
                src={
                  "http://130.61.61.186:8055/assets/" +
                  item.images +
                  "?access_token=mrfcaiL5UrlAu_zsWeADkwKKXFLxJK41"
                }

                className={styles.image}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </section>
       
      </article>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)